Как получить родителский элемент по содержимому двух дочерних элементов?
У меня есть список событий со следующим содержимым:
<div class="all-events">
    <div class="sport-base-event__main__right--xcugF">
        <div class="event-block-current-time--fU6oM">
            <span class="svg-resource--QrfQ8 event-block-current-time__icon-watch--tJlx1" resource-name="timer">
            </span>
            <span class="event-block-current-time__time--VEuoj">29:16</span>
        </div>
        <div class="event-block-score--QKiav _compact--hwFo7">
            <span class="event-block-score__score--r0ZU9">0:0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="sport-base-event__main__right--xcugF">
        <div class="event-block-current-time--fU6oM">
            <span class="svg-resource--QrfQ8 event-block-current-time__icon-watch--tJlx1" resource-name="timer">
            </span>
            <span class="event-block-current-time__time--VEuoj">30:16</span>
        </div>
        <div class="event-block-score--QKiav _compact--hwFo7">
            <span class="event-block-score__score--r0ZU9">0:0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="sport-base-event__main__right--xcugF">
        <div class="event-block-current-time--fU6oM">
            <span class="svg-resource--QrfQ8 event-block-current-time__icon-watch--tJlx1" resource-name="timer">
            </span>
            <span class="event-block-current-time__time--VEuoj">29:16</span>
        </div>
        <div class="event-block-score--QKiav _compact--hwFo7">
            <span class="event-block-score__score--r0ZU9">1:0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Я пытаюсь использовать следующий код
//div[@class="sport-base-event__main__right--xcugF"]/div[span[contains(text(),"29")] and span[text()="0:0"]]

Как правильно отредактировать запрос и получить родительский элемент если время события содержит значение 29 и счет равен 0:0?

//div[@class='sport-base-event__main__right--xcugF'][div[span[contains(text(),'29')]] and div[span[text()='0:0']]]

@AlexanderPetrov
Спасибо! Работает.
